Generating multiple activities with different structures using mistral and guidance library
I'm currently working on a project where I need to generate a list of three different activities, each following the same structure. I have successfully generated one activity using mistral and the guidance library. The activities have various fields such as type, description, example, etc., and each field should be chosen from a predefined list.
However, when I attempt to generate two more activities using the same method, I find that the same activity is generated multiple times, rather than three different activities.( by the way each the activities are based on a given student profile)
I successfully generated one activity that meets all the criteria: it corresponds to the student's profile and adheres to the specified fields (there are various combinations of fields, with each type corresponding to a specific description). I achieved this using guidance. However, when attempting to generate the other two activities, I encountered an issue. Despite changing the prompts and attempting various approaches including using loops, I still end up with the same activity being generated repeatedly
